# Docker mysql 8 - cannot bind a mysql folder to Windows 10 folder. Get an mbind error

Tags: mysql, docker

About a year ago I could bind mount a Windows folder to the Docker MySql folder.

When trying to do the same with Docker MySql 8.0.12 I cannot bind a windows folder to MySql. I see in the log of mysql that mbind: operation not permitted.

```
services:
  mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:8.0.12
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=spring_app_db
      - MYSQL_USER=app_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
    volumes:
      - k:/zut/docker/storage:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
```

The folder is an existing, but empty folder. I see all kinds of posts, but no easy solution. Can you help me finding that good solution? I removed all previous containers and images.

When trying to re-install MySql 5.7.* or 5.6 I get all kinds of errors.

I can see that the Windows folder stays empty.

Should I configure something in the Virtualbox? A shared folder or so? A year ago I did have to do this.

The log info (on request) is:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose2.yml up
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Starting dockercomposespringbootmysql_mysql-docker-container_1 ... done
Attaching to dockercomposespringbootmysql_mysql-docker-container_1
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:15.776081Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:15.776168Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 1
mysql-docker-container_1  | mbind: Operation not permitted
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:15.986113Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.053452Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.060630Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.060890Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.061308Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.061722Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.062252Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.062621Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.063088Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.068879Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql-docker-container_1  | 2018-09-02T13:53:16.069353Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
```

Comment: are you trying to mount a folder, which was mysql 5.* previously?

Comment: No, a fresh clean one.

Comment: `mbind: operation not permitted.` is a warning, not an error. Please post the _complete_ logs

Comment: Done, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1: shared folders via Oracle VM Virtualbox**

Start your Oracle VM Virtualbox and have the 'default' virtual machine running. Select that 'default' > the settings > the shared folders. Add a shared folder name = 'd/zut', folder on windows = 'd:\zut' and give it all permissions and keep it persistant.

In the docker-compose file you can use that mapping:

```
volumes:
  - //d/zut:/var/lib/mysql
```

**Answer 2: named volumes**

If you are facing problems with the first solution, you can use docker 'named volumes'. Docker manages the persistant volumes. It's a bit more trickier to access the data ;-)

In the docker-compose.yml file add (with before the first 'zut' no '/')

```
services:
  mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:8.0.12
      environment:
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=*** etc etc
    volumes:
      - zut:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"

  volumes:
    zut:
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently enabled the windows docker desktop to use WSL 2 based engine as well as installed ubuntu and it seems that one or the other changed the mount path of my drives. For the "D://***" drive, I had the docker compose volume set as "/d/some/folder", but after some digging the path is now "/mnt/d/some/folder".